# Passing parameters to a method called by NSTimer in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nstimer

I'm trying to pass an argument to a method that is called by NSTimer in my code. It is throwing an exception. This is how I'm doing it. Circle is my custom class.

```
    var circle = Circle()
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: animate, userInfo: circle, repeats: true)
```

Below is the method that is being called

```
    func animate(circle: Circle) -> Void{
      //do stuff with circle
    }
```

Note: The method is in the same class that it is being called. So I believe i've set the target correctly.

Answer (score 41):

The selector you use with `NSTimer` is passed the `NSTimer` object as it's one and only parameter. Put the circle object in it as `userInfo` and you can extract it when the timer fires.

```
var circle = Circle()
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "animate:", userInfo: circle, repeats: true)

func animate(timer:NSTimer){
  var circle = timer.userInfo as Circle
  //do stuff with circle
}
```

Comment: How about two parameters?

Comment: pass the two parameters as a tuple to userInfo? or make a custom struct that encapsulates the two params? I'm not able to try this right now, bt maybe that gives you a hint. ask again if you are still stuck

Answer (score 0):

Your selector needs to be a string unless that's supposed to be an ivar. Also, your `animate` function has the wrong signature. The following changes should get you moving again:

```
var circle = Circle()
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "animate", userInfo: circle, repeats: true)

func animate(circle: Circle) -> () {
  //do stuff with circle
}
```

The function really doesn't need to return the empty tuple; it can be written without the `-> ()`

I've also seen the selector string wrapped in a "Selector()" method: `Selector("animate")`. It works either way.

I've been messing with `NSTimer` and closures myself and wrote an article on it: [Using Swift's Closures With NSTimer](http://www.samuelmullen.com/2014/07/using-swifts-closures-with-nstimer/)

Comment: String replacement in Xcode : @"bla bla";
String replacement in Swift : "bla bla"

So this is correct answer.

Comment: Still does not seem to work. I get the following error message

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10da13d60'

Comment: The circle argument can't be passed, but it looks like it's already a property. try:
func animate() {
  //do stuff with self.circle
}

Comment: Well that's the problem. I have a lot of circle objects that need to be animated periodically. So they need to be passed into that method

Comment: `selector: "animate"` should be `selector: "animate:"`.