# Xcode , Swift - How to use a function that takes a parameter as a selector

Tags: xcode, function, swift, selector

I have a function that takes an integer, but i would like to use it as a selector and pass a parameter to it.

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "addAmount", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

 func addAmount(amount: Int) {

    money += amount


}
```

Comment: ... and the correct answer is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26359761/1187415.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [NSTimer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html):

> The selector should have the following signature: timerFireMethod: (including a colon to indicate that the method takes an argument). The timer passes itself as the argument, thus the method would adopt the following pattern:
>   `- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer *)timer`

So you can write a function with that signature, then call your `addAmount` function inside it.

```
func timerFireMethod(timer: NSTimer) {
    addAmount(SOME_AMOUNT)
}
```

Then schedule the timer with

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "timerFireMethod:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: Thnx a lot, that worked!