# Swift NSTimer makes app crash

Tags: ios, swift

When called, the app crashes.

```
func handlers() {
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5,
    target: self, selector: "timeListener", userInfo: data, repeats: true)
}

func timeListener(timer:NSTimer) {
    var data: AnyObject? = timer.userInfo
    println(data);
}
```

Tried a few things, tried another answer ([Passing parameters to a method called by NSTimer in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889279/passing-parameters-to-a-method-called-by-nstimer-in-swift)) but every code made the app crash still. What's wrong in this code?

Comment: What's the exact crash message?

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Smartass. didn't even see that other message, still getting around the Xcode IDE.

Comment: And an IDE message will never give a nice, specific answer like NobodyNada did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the selector to `timeListener:` (note the colon).

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5,
target: self, selector: "timeListener:", userInfo: data, repeats: true)
```

This is because in Objective-C,

```
func timeListener(timer:NSTimer)
```

would be written as

```
-(void)timeListener:(NSTimer*)timer
```

You need to add a colon everywhere the function wants an argument.